# Streaming Videos

Tags: video, web, webserver, video-streaming, jwplayer

I implemented JWPlayer for some of streaming videos we have. The idea was to protect the videos from getting downloaded using addons and plugins. But unfortunately, we noticed that addons like `DownloadHelper` for Firefox.

What we did is this

1. we uploaded the video to JWPlayer website
2. They do streaming over there
3. we have taken the embeded code and attached it to the player
4. now our player is streaming the video

At the same time, we found that videos in some websites are not downloadable, even they used the same player. Following is an example.

http://www.rupavahini.lk/index.php/rupavahini-documentary/sarisara/1061-2013-11-17

So, what is the secret here? Even both sites use the same player, why my videos are still downloadable? I know we can't stop all the addons and plugins, but compared to the given site, the percentage risk in my site is high. Please help.

Comment: Is this example your site? This has RTMP, so it provides some security, but can still be ripped. We have a blog here about this - http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/securing-your-content/

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer: Hi, Thank you for the reply. So how they do RTMP? Are they using a RTMP Server like Wowza?

Comment: Yes, they are using RTMP - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28854/using-rtmp-streaming

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer: Thanks a lot for the info Ethan. Will get back to you in case I have more questions.

Comment: No problem, any time~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you pointed to is not using http to play the stream. It uses RTMP. The stream is still rip-able using a tool like rtmpdump.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. So how they do RTMP? Are they using a RTMP Server like Wowza?